# Inaccurate Asset Balances

Tags: wavesplatform

I’ve noticed that when I fetch balances from the Waves Platform API, my reported balances can vary and seem to be reported inaccurately at times.  Is this a common issue?  Is there maybe a delay in updating balances after trades?

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This usually happen when:
1. You are using official Waves nodes pool (nodes.wavesnodes.com) - some responses are cached.
2. At the moment of request generating node and your node are not synced yet. In this way you have to wait few seconds to let new micro blocks to sync up.